# Embedding CF populated pdfs

Tags: pdf, coldfusion

I am using coldfusion and trying to figure out how to embed pdfs that are populated using a cfm.

What I have is a `forms/82040PDFCreator.cfm` that populates a pdf like so:

```
<cfpdfform source="../../../../forms/82040_wValidFieldNames.pdf" action="populate" destination="#tempFilePath#">
  <cfif session.checkout.vehicle.SP eq "Yes">
    <cfpdfformparam name="specialty_plate" value="Specialty Plate: #session.checkout.vehicle.data_code#"> <!---Above Section1 Original --->
    <cfpdfformparam name="specialty_plate_name" value="#session.checkout.vehicle.data_name#">
  </cfif>
</cfpdfform>
<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="attachment;filename=82040.pdf">
<cfcontent type="application/pdf" file="#tempFilePath#" deleteFile="true">
```

When I create a link calling `forms/82040PDFCreator.cfm` it opens the pdf correctly because it downloads it.

When I try embedding it though the cfm fails to load.

```
<embed
    type="application/pdf"
    src="forms/82040PDFCreator.cfm"
    id="pdfDocument"
    width="100%"
    height="100%" />
```

Its strange though if I directly call the pdf it will open though. Just not the cfm that populates the pdf.

```
<embed
    type="application/pdf"
    src="../../../forms/82040_wValidFieldNames.pdf"
    id="pdfDocument"
    width="100%"
    height="100%" />
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

I have also tried doing includes. Which will download them as well.

My goal is to be able to have a print button that will print many pdfs at once.

Comment: I'd think content-disposition "attachment" and `<embed>` would be mutually exclusive.  This seems kinda convoluted and brittle.  What about merging the files instead?

Comment: do you know how to merge without having it run terribly slow?

Comment: Define "terribly slow". How many files and how long?

Comment: oh i dont know how to do it. Iv just read other ppl say theyve used pdf.js to do it and that on ipads or mobile devices its horribly slow

Comment: I was talking about server side merging.

Comment: how do you do that?

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=coldfusion+merge+pdf&ia=web